# ASP.NET Core Web App using Work (Azure AD) Authentication works debugging locally, but not after publish to Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

My ASP.NET Core web app works great when running and debugging locally, but fails to run once published to Azure.

- I enabled Organizational Authentication and selected the appropriate domain upon publishing.
- The appropriate reply URL was registered

After I publish to Azure I get this error:

**An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.**
OpenIdConnectProtocolException: Message contains error: 'invalid_client', error_description: 'AADSTS70002: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_secret or client_assertion'.
Trace ID: 640186d6-9a50-4fce-ae39-bbfc1caf2400
Correlation ID: 622758b2-ca52-4bb0-9a98-e14d5a45cf80
Timestamp: 2017-04-19 16:36:32Z', error_uri: 'error_uri is null'.

I'm assuming that it's because the Client Secret needs to be stored in Azure somewhere; however, the value in secrets.json did not work when I added it as an App Setting (invalid client secret error) as I saw someone was able to do on another post. Also not sure if putting the value of "Authentication:AzureAd:ClientSecret" in Azure AppSettings is a good idea anyway.

Comment: Does it work if you place them in Azure AppSettings?

Comment: If included in AppSettings, I get a different error: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectProtocolException: Message contains error: 'invalid_client', error_description: 'AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50012: Invalid client secret is provided.

Comment: Look at the screen shots at my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreAzureAD#azure-portal---app-registrations---step-1), and see which step you missed.

Comment: Okay, I got it to work as the ClientID locally was pointing to a different registered App ID on Azure. So when I replaced the ClientId in App Settings, it worked. However, is that where I should put both the client and the secret IDs?

Comment: When I encountered a similar issue it was due to the fact that the hosting needs to be setup as a Native application

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is useful to anyone or not. But i receive a similar error message.

```
OpenIdConnectProtocolException: Message contains error: 'invalid_client', error_description: 'error_description is null', error_uri: 'error_uri is null'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler+<RedeemAuthorizationCodeAsync>d__22.MoveNext()
```

The solution for me was to provide a secret in the token service

```
,new Client
            {
                ClientId = "Testclient",
                ClientName = "client",
                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },
                //Hybrid is a mix between implicit and authorization flow
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Hybrid,
```

And provide the secret in the client

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
            {
                //The name of the authentication configuration.. just incase we have multiple
                AuthenticationScheme = "oidc",
                //Represents where to store the identity information -> which points to the cookie middleware declared above
                SignInScheme = "Cookies",

                //where the token service reside -> system will configure itself by invoking the discovery endpoint for the token service
                Authority = "http://localhost:5000",
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false,

            ClientId = "Testclient",
            ClientSecret = "secret",
            //hybrid flow -grant type
            ResponseType = "code id_token",
```

Hopefully this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I the Azure AD IDs needed for the proper Azure Active Directory App Registration were mixed up. There were 2 App Registration entries and the ClientID and TenentID's didn't match up with the local. So I synchronized the Client and Tenent IDs with one of the App Registration entries, and made sure the Client Secret was in App Settings, and it worked properly.

I verified these steps with this fine example [Win's GitHub repository](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreAzureAD#azure-portal---app-registrations---step-1) and they match now.